# how to filter woocommerce products based on discount wise?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I work my first WordPress eCommerce store.i want to product filter based on discount.i use woo-commerce product filter but i confused how to make discount wise filtration in my store.

```
like UPTO 10%
     10%-20%
     20%-30%
     -------
     -------
    more 50%
```

http://screencast.com/t/sNRvMFrtxVe

thanks